# Restricting Authors to View and Edit Only Posts they Created in PHP (I'm not using WordPress)

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this query:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON $mydb.*
    TO '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$username'"
```

It grants `select` and `insert` in phpMyAdmin, and it works perfectly (as I wanted) in phpMyAdmin.

But when I login to my PHP site with this username, I can edit or delete all the posts and I want to restrict this user in the PHP site also.

I'm a beginner so could anyone please tell me how to achieve this in PHP also?

I want the particular author to only create a new post, edit, or delete his post only.

Thanks, and sorry if I sound confusing or incomplete.

---

Thanks for the quick reply both.

I already created a table for users with:

```
userid | username | pass | role | etc
```

Here I can get `role` from table `roles`:

```
roleid | role
```

Now, I need help here:

Now, from that `role` set condition for which user can add a post, which user can delete the post, and which user can edit the post?

Any code sample or example?

Answer (score 0):

You should always have user access in your user management class in your php.

Store your user access in your database, always check if your user has the permissions to do the right action.

For a simple user access class, you can set "editor" user access to "edit" in your db. Whenever this user tries to delete a post, check if he has the access. If not for example you can redirect him or show him that he do not have access.

Comment: thanks for replying,as im beginner any example or code will help

Comment: First you should create your user management table. For example: Table users (`id`,`username`,`pass`,`email`,user_access`), and when registering user you insert values like this (`,"test","test","test@test.com","editor"). When a user logged in store his access on a global var like $_SESSION. On the editors.php page when someone click on the delete check access, like: if($_SESSION['user_access']=="editor") return "you do not permissions to delete this post". Ofcourse this is a simple way. You should store page accesses in your database and user accesses and it's better to have stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON $mydb.*
            TO '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$username'"
```

what your above query do is just apply privilege to some user to access database with `$username` there is nothing to do with edit post and delete post.

To achieve your desire what you need to do is.

create database with desired table with one table of roles which manage user authentication.

now from that role set condition for which user can add post which user can delete post and which user can edit post and so on..

Comment: i already created table for users with 

          userid | username | pass | role | etc 

here i get role from table roles

          roleid | role |  
now need hele here
now from that role set condition for which user can add post which user can delete post and which user can edit post